# Modify boot.img of Moto G 2014 ROM

Tags: custom-roms, boot, rom

Starting from the Titan Prime ROM I would like to make some modifications to the boot.img. But if I try to unpack and repack the boot.img the phone jumps immediately into the bootloader after the start and says 'Fastboot Reason: Fall-through from normal boot mode'.

I hoped you could have a look at my workflow and tell me what I am doing wrong:

First I take your Rom and unzip it:

```
$ unzip TitanPrimeROMv1.0.2-XT1068-69.zip -d Titan
$ cd Titan
```

Here is what the boot_info tells me:

```
$ boot_info boot.img                                             
PAGE SIZE: 2048
BASE ADDRESS: 0x00000000
RAMDISK ADDRESS: 0x01000000
CMDLINE: 'console=ttyHSL0,115200,n8 androidboot.console=ttyHSL0 androidboot.hardware=qcom user_debug=31 msm_rtb.filter=0x37 vmalloc=400M utags.blkdev=/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/utags'
```

Then I unpack the boot image:

```
$ unpack boot.img 
Boot = boot.img
unmkbootimg version 1.2 - Mikael Q Kuisma <kuisma@ping.se>
Kernel size 6449544
Kernel address 0x8000
Ramdisk size 807152
Ramdisk address 0x1000000
Secondary size 0
Secondary address 0xf00000
Kernel tags address 0x100
Flash page size 2048
Board name is ""
Command line "console=ttyHSL0,115200,n8 androidboot.console=ttyHSL0 androidboot.hardware=qcom user_debug=31 msm_rtb.filter=0x37 vmalloc=400M utags.blkdev=/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/utags"
This image is built using standard mkbootimg
Extracting kernel to file zImage ...
Extracting root filesystem to file initramfs.cpio.gz ...
All done.
---------------
To recompile this image, use:
$ mkbootimg --kernel zImage --ramdisk initramfs.cpio.gz --base 0x0 --cmdline 'console=ttyHSL0,115200,n8 androidboot.console=ttyHSL0 androidboot.hardware=qcom user_debug=31 msm_rtb.filter=0x37 vmalloc=400M utags.blkdev=/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/utags' -o new_boot.img
---------------
2974 blocks
```

Now I make some minor modification to the boot image like adding a file:

```
$ touch boot/ramdisk/hello_ramdisk
```

Then I try to rebuild the ramdisk:

```
$ mkbootimg --kernel boot/zImage --ramdisk boot/new-ramdisk.cpio.gz --base 0x0 --cmdline 'console=ttyHSL0,115200,n8 androidboot.console=ttyHSL0 androidboot.hardware=qcom user_debug=31 msm_rtb.filter=0x37 vmalloc=400M utags.blkdev=/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/utags' -o boot.img
```

I remove the boot folder, zip it and sign it:

```
$ mv boot ../
$ zip -r myrom.zip
$ java -classpath /opt/android-sdk/tools/sign/testsign.jar testsign myrom.zip myrom-signed.zip
```

Then I place the file on the sdcard and try to install it via TWRP ‘Install’.

Comment: Where did you get "Titan Prime ROM"? Is it directly from Motorola? Thanks!

Comment: No, it's from xda.